# implementation of member functions of a class should be in one .cpp file?

Tags: c++

Recently, I write a class of C++ with .h and .cpp files. In the scope of my knowledge, all member data and functions declarated in the .h file, the implementations of functions are in .cpp file. But when the codes of functions in cpp file are huge, it is looks littery.

So, there is some suggestions?

Comment: Explain what you mean by "looks littery".  You are free to split up your class implementation into multiple files.  There are only basic conventions.  Of course, if your class is freakin' enormous, it's probably a design issue more than a source file issue.

Comment: The linker only cares whether `all` members are defined.
It does not care `where` they are defined

Comment: @paddy, Hi paddy, "looks littery" means there are two many codes in a single file, it is not easy to read. Ok, I wil search the ways to split up my class implementation. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Raildex, thanks, I will google it.

Comment: You may have created a class that's too big.

Comment: If the biggest issue with your code is that there's a lot of it, count yourself lucky.  For most of us in production, that kind of clean-up is an unattainable luxury.  My main project has hundreds of source files, and most of them contain many thousand lines of code.

Comment: You should find venues for reducing code duplication, and splitting up classes along orthogonal concerns.